# Asp.net identity - Reset cookies and session on iis recycle (restart)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-identity

I have implemented asp.net mvc with asp.net identity authentication.

I have used cookie based authentication. After restart the IIS/stop and start the IIS for the my site, when i open my website, the user is automatically login to the system.

The user cookie is not cleared and still valid for the user. How to force the user to log out after restart the iis?

I have used default sample from the website.
http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples

[image]

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, I have done a trick.

We are using **session** to store the **dynamic variables** and **asp.net identity** for authentication in **ASP.NET MVC**.

1. Each request I have interrupted.
2. I have checked like whether asp.net identity is valid and session is invalid.
3. If session is invalid, then make the cookies invalid and navigate the user to specific page.

   ```
   public class SessionHandler : ActionFilterAttribute
   {
       private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
       private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
       {
           get
           {
               return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
           }
       }
       public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
       {
           get
           {
               return _userManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
           }
           private set
           {
               _userManager = value;
           }
       }
       public IIdentity UserIdentity
       {
           get { return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity; }
       }

       public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
       {

           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserIdentity.GetUserId()))
           {
               if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"] == null)
               {
                   AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
                   filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                 new RouteValueDictionary
                                 {
                                      { "action", "Index" },
                                      { "controller", "Home" }
                                 });
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

**In Global.asax file**

Add the following code

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new SessionHandler());
```

Comment: So on login you always add `Username` to the session?

Answer (score 3):

Cookies are not meant to be invalidated when IIS is restarted - this is not how HTTP protocol works. Cookies being invalidated on IIS restart can lead to some strange behaviour in production - IIS can be plunged any time, or there could be load-balancer that uses a few IIS servers to serve the requests - what would happen if one of the servers restarts?

Anyway, you can kill all the cookies for all the users by mass-updating  `ApplicationUser.SecurityStamp` in the database. And in `Startup.Auth.cs` set `validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)` - this will invalidate all the cookies within 2 minutes of the SecurityStamp update. Value lower than this is not recommended - this will cause performance issues.

Comment: But usually, session will be invalid if iis restart. Then why doesn't happen here.

Comment: Identity does not use session

Comment: Yes you are right. :-) But even if you use bearer token, the token will be expired after restart iis.

Comment: @JeevaJsb I don't think tokens depend on IIS either. Anyway, what is your use case? why do you need to kick users out on some arbitrary condition?

Comment: We are using session too with Asp.net identity instead of refresh tokens. So sessions will be invalid on IIS restart. So we need to invalidate the Cookies after iis restart.